# Why can't my Grails app get an object from my Angular script?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, grails

I'm trying to add objects to a JSON list in Grails. Here's my Angular code:
http://pastebin.com/4ypijUMD

And my Grails controller:
http://pastebin.com/skTtVtxv

From my understanding, my angularJS script should send a request to access the add controller with the info from the most recent member of the list.

Then the add function should create a new JSON object based off the parameters passed into the controller from the angular script, and ta-da.

However, nothing is created, I just get null objects when I try to update my

```
list with my update controller:
    def saveList() {
        def newItem = Item.findById(request.JSON.id)
        newItem.name = request.JSON.name
        newItem.type = request.JSON.type
        newItem.priority = request.JSON.priority
        newItem.completed = request.JSON.completed
        newItem.save(flush: true)
        render newItem as JSON
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the code making the actual AJAX call, just a service with a save call. The way you do this with Grails and Angular would look something like this:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/test-app/myController/addItem', { json values})
    .success(function(response) {})
    .error(function(response) {});

class MyController {
    def addItem() {}
}
```

Comment: What would I put in place of json values?

Answer (score 0):

In your pastbin code I saw that, you send a list from the browser and work on an single item in the server code. May this be the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you are not passing request.JSON.id from angular.

```
                              {                                
                                 id: 1
                                 name: $scope.thing,
                                 type: $scope.worktypeSelection,
                                 priority: $scope.prioritySelection,
                                 completed: false
                                }
```